# replacing float to double via whole project

Tags: java

I have a legacy project and it has math that uses float and long variables like this:

```
long i = initWihtVeryBigNumber();
float multiplier = 1.3f;
i *= multiplier;
```

this basically cause round error due to float size and this has to be replaced with:

```
i = (long)( i* (double)multiplier );
```

or multiplier itself should be double instead of float.

So the question if I change through entire project float to double could this cause any unpredictable behavior or not ? If so can you provide any example that can produce a problem ?

Comment: If you want precise decimal number, use `java.math.BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: I dont know for sure, but it is possible that some methods could be relying float behaviour. You should write a bunch of test cases, do the refactor, and find out.

Comment: Make sure you also change `1.3f` to `1.3d` or just `1.3`.  If you say `double multiplier = 1.3f`, I believe it will create a 32-bit float and then convert it to 64 bits, which means you will not be getting as close to `1.3` as you could.  Neither `float` nor `double` will represent `1.3` exactly, but the error will be greater with `float`.  I'm just saying this because I don't know if you were planning to do a simple text substitution `float` -> `double` in an editor.

Comment: In calculations the float is promoted to double, and in `i = 6L; i *= 1.5f;` the value of `i` will be 9L. It is more the question whether float and double should not be replaced with BigDecimal, for correct rounding. (Horrible work.)

Comment: @JoopEggen float multiplier = 27.5f; long i = 86250000; gives 2371875072 and double multiplier = 27.5; long i = 86250000 - 2371875000

Comment: 27.5 can be represented exactly in both a `float` and a `double`, so I would not expect the choice of float or double to make a difference in this case.  1.3 is different.

Comment: "if I change through entire project float to double...?"  Your program _will_ produce different intermediate values, and may therefore produce different final results.  There's no way for anybody to know whether the difference will be an improvement, or whether it will cause "unpredictable behavior" without seeing the whole program and understanding how its output is used.

Comment: @YuliMatsai thanks for answering all those comments. **(1)** Floating point is an approximation of (positive/negative) powers of 2, and will always give errors, `float` more than `double`. **(2)** The legacy rounding to long even might be an ill devised attempt to solve this issue. **(3)** switching to `double` might be unsatisfactory. **(4)** In a similar case, I did not only switch to BigDecimal, but handled formatting i.a. with decimal comma i.o. point. Maybe the surrounding code can be consolidated into a single call to one or two repeated new functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the question if I change through entire project float to double could this cause any unpredictable behavior or not ? If so can you provide any example that can produce a problem ?

Yes. Changing `(float)` to `(double)` could cause issues, whenever the method requires a `float`. For example,

```
Float.toString((double) 1.0f);
```

Is a compilation error.

**Edit**

> I'm interested in run-time errors rather then in compilation errors.

Okay. You have a third party library that returns a `List<Float>` (so `testIt()` below is from a third party). If you blindly cast elements from that `List` to `Float` you will get a run-time error.

```
public static List<Float> testIt() {
    List<Float> al = new ArrayList<Float>();
    al.add(1.0f);
    return al;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<?> al = testIt();
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        Object o = al.get(i);
        Double v = (Double) o;
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: So your response should be no. It will not cause unpredictable problems, if you remember to also change `Float` to `Double` for the entire project.

Comment: @Oran `float` != `Float`, and `double` != `Double`. It also could be impacted by third party libraries that expect the other type.

Comment: I'm interested in run-time errors rather then in compilation errors

Comment: @ElliottFrisch great, it's going to work, but it's a bit artificial, however your are right theoretically it might happens

Answer (score 2):

Another difference is that unlike `float`, writes to non-volatile `double` fields aren't guaranteed to be atomic.

It is an unlikely scenario that only affects multi-threaded systems that haven't been synchronized correctly but boy does it cause unexpected runtime problems.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're still going to get rounding errors even if you change floats to doubles.  Example: suppose we set `i` to 3703816849309525656 (= `3 * 0x1122334455667788`, just a number I tried as an experiment).

```
long i = 3703816849309525656L;
float multiplier = 1.3f;
i *= multiplier;
System.out.println(i);
```

outputs

```
4814961529147359232

long i = 3703816849309525656L;
double multiplier = 1.3;
i *= multiplier;
System.out.println(i);
```

outputs

```
4814961904102383616
```

But using a calculator program (GNU `bc`):

```
(3703816849309525656 * 13) / 10
4814961904102383352.8
```

So using a `double` gets you a lot closer, but the result is still incorrect; and when one deals with integers, one normally expects exact results.  Therefore, I'd consider using `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`, although I realize that change would require a lot more effort.